# How to pass one entry from a list as prop in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, prop

Lets say I have the following list in data:

```
data: {
    todos: [
      { id: 1, title: "Learn Python" },
      { id: 2, title: "Learn JS" },
      { id: 3, title: "Create WebApp" }
    ]
  }
```

Now I want to pass only the entry with id of 2 to the prop:

```
<dynamic-prop :id=todos[2] :title="todos.title"> </dynamic-prop>
```

Is something like that possible in Vue?

Comment: I don't know if it would work but you could try
`<dynamic-prop :id="todos.find(element => element.id == 2).id" :title="todos.find(element => element.id == 2).title"> </dynamic-prop>`

Comment: @paul-shuvo Please no complex logic inside HTML. Use a _computed prop_ for things like that. Computed props are calculated only once for a given state; your solution would run the search twice (besides being hard to read and maintain).

Comment: @Quoting Eddie, that's why it's a comment, not an answer; it's more like a quick fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can pass any `data` on. Just don't forget to add quotation marks and mind the off-by-one problem. So if you want to pass the *second* element in a (zero-indexed) array, you'd write something like:

```
<dynamic-prop :id="todos[1].id" :title="todos[1].title"> </dynamic-prop>
```

Comment: Or better yet - use a computed property to get the desired element from the list, then reference the computed property in your component's props.

Comment: How about based on certain entry value not index?

Comment: Something like where todos.id=="2"

Comment: Can you change your data structure? It would become a lot easier if it were without an array but directly an object. `todos: { 1: { title: "Learn Python" }, 2: { title: "..."} }`. Then you can access it by `todos[id]` where `id` is the actual ID. Otherwise consider computed props (see official Vue.js docs).